# Telegram bot message forwarding on schedule

Tags: python, bots, python-asyncio, python-telegram-bot

I would like to forward messages from one telegram channel to another in a given time. I'm using the python-telegram-bot v20.0 library for this. Without scheduling it works like a charm, but when trying to schedule it doesn't give an error, but runs forever and nothing happens.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from telegram import Bot
import asyncio


BOT = Bot(...)
CHANNEL_FROM = ...
CHANNEL_TO = ...
MESSAGE_ID = 97
TIME = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)


async def prepare_message():
    message_status = await BOT.forward_message(chat_id=CHANNEL_TO, from_chat_id=CHANNEL_FROM, message_id=MESSAGE_ID)
    if message_status:
        print(f"Scheduled message {MESSAGE_ID} sent successfully.")


async def send_message():
    # That doesn't work
    for i in range(2):
        scheduler.add_job(prepare_message, 'date', run_date=TIME)
        print(f"Added job to send message {MESSAGE_ID} from channel {CHANNEL_FROM} to channel {CHANNEL_TO} at {TIME}")
    
    # That works
    message_status = await BOT.forward_message(chat_id=CHANNEL_TO, from_chat_id=CHANNEL_FROM, message_id=MESSAGE_ID)
    if message_status:
        print(f"Regular message {MESSAGE_ID} sent successfully")


scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(send_message, "interval", days=1, start_date="2022-01-01 00:00:00", timezone="UTC")
scheduler.start()

asyncio.run(send_message())

while True:
    pass
```

The output of this snippet is

```
Added job to send message 97 from channel ... to channel ... at 2023-01-24 20:51:16.471834
Added job to send message 97 from channel ... to channel ... at 2023-01-24 20:51:16.471834
Regular message 97 sent successfully
```

Would be grateful if anyone could help me make it work.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    pass
```

will not give the event loop a chance to do anything, as this loop is blocking. As your main goal seems to be to have the scheduler running forever, I recommend to have a look at the [`APScheduler` examples](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/3.x/examples/schedulers/asyncio_.py).